# infile class. Constructor undefined

Tags: java

It keeps telling me that my constructor Pet is undefined. Any ideas?

I've tried defining Pet in my main method prior to the while loop, but it gives me the same issue.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadPets
{
     public static void main (String[] args)
     {

          ArrayList <Pet> petList = new ArrayList <Pet>();
          Scanner inFile = null;
          String name;
          Pet p;
          try
          {
               inFile = new Scanner
               (new FileInputStream ("pets.txt"));
          }

          catch(FileNotFoundException e)
          {
               System.out.println("problem opening file.");
               System.exit(0);
          }
          while (inFile.hasNextLine())
          {
               name = inFile.nextLine();
               p = new Pet(name); // here is where my error is
               petList.add(p);
          }
          inFile.close();
     }
}
```

Here is my Pet class.

```
public class Pet
{
     private String name;
     private int age; //in years
     private double weight; //in pounds

     /**
      This main is just a demonstration program.
     */
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         Pet myDog = new Pet( );
         myDog.set("Fido", 2, 5.5);
         myDog.writeOutput( );
         System.out.println("Changing name.");
         myDog.set("Rex");
         myDog.writeOutput( );
         System.out.println("Changing weight.");
         myDog.set(6.5);
         myDog.writeOutput( );
         System.out.println("Changing age.");
         myDog.set(3);
         myDog.writeOutput( );
     }

     public void writeOutput( )
     {
         System.out.println("Name: " + name);
         System.out.println("Age: " + age + " years");
         System.out.println("Weight: " + weight + " pounds");
     }

     public void set(String newName)
     {
         name = newName;
         //age and weight are unchanged.
     }

     public void set(int newAge)
     {
         if (newAge <= 0)
         {
             System.out.println("Error: illegal age.");
             System.exit(0);
         }
         else
             age = newAge;
         //name and weight are unchanged.
     }

     public void set(double newWeight)
     {
         if (newWeight <= 0)
         {
             System.out.println("Error: illegal weight.");
             System.exit(0);
         }
         else
             weight = newWeight;
         //name and age are unchanged.
     }

     public void set(String newName, int newAge, double newWeight)
     {
         name = newName;
         if ((newAge <= 0) || (newWeight <= 0))
         {
             System.out.println("Error: illegal age or weight.");
             System.exit(0);
         }
         else
         {
             age = newAge;
             weight = newWeight;
         }
     }

     public String getName( )
     {
         return name;
     }


     public int getAge( )
     {
         return age;
     }
     public double getWeight( )
     {
         return weight;
     }
}
```

Comment: Post you `Pet` class. Does it have a constructor that takes a String as an arg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Pet` class does not have a constructor that takes a `String` which is what you are trying with this line

```
p = new Pet(name)
```

Either make one or do something similar to the demonstration, which is make the new `Pet` instance and then call `set("Name")` on this instance

Like:

```
p = new Pet();
p.set(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any constructors in your `Pet` class which means that Java will provide a default (no argument) constructor for you.

This is why the following statement is OK:

```
Pet myDog = new Pet( );
```

The statement that you have a problem with uses a **constructor with an argument**, that you have not defined.

You will need either to create such constructor (`Pet(String name) {...}`) or change your logic to use default constructor and your `set()` method.

Be warned as soon as you define any constructor, Java will no longer create a default constructor for you, so you will need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You required to write one parametrized constructor in our Pet class with one String.